# How to: Center collection view content after a cell gets removed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view UI setup to the following methods.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.testSlice.count
    }
```

This method ^ represents the collection views data source, which is an array of `strings`. These strings are ID's for profile pictures, I am handling the case of `requesting a profile picture, and getting nothing in return` explained in the method below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        cell.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true

        print("DEV: testSlice value: \(testSlice)")
        print("DEV: limitedNames value: \(limitedNames)")

        if testSlice != [] {
            cell.profilePicture.playPortalProfilePic(forImageId: testSlice[indexPath.item], { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error requesting profile pic: \(String(describing: error))")
                    cell.isHidden = true


                }
            }
            )
        } else {
            print("items array was empty, value: \(items)")
        }



        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        return cell
    }
```

In the line that says `if let error = error` I hide the cell that returned the error. The problem is, this could be in the middle of the collection view UI leaving a big empty space. Looking for recommendations on how to center the UI / update it after the cell with the error is hidden.

Comment: All you are doing is leaving the cell in place but invisible. So the space is not empty at all; your cell is occupying it. Instead of testing this here and hiding the cell, test it elsewhere, remove the corresponding cell data from the data model, and reload the collection view. Things will just close up automatically. Look at how the Photos app behaves when you delete a photo from the grid, for example.

Comment: @matt Thank you for pointing that out - solved it like this 
`if let index = self.testSlice.index(of: "") {
                        self.testSlice.remove(at: index)
                        collectionView.reloadData()
                    }`

Comment: That's the spirit, well done.

Answer (score 0):

@matt pointed out this - All you are doing is leaving the cell in place but invisible. So the space is not empty at all; your cell is occupying it. Instead of testing this here and hiding the cell, test it elsewhere, remove the corresponding cell data from the data model, and reload the collection view. Things will just close up automatically. Look at how the Photos app behaves when you delete a photo from the grid, for example

Solved like this:

```
if let index = self.testSlice.index(of: "") { self.testSlice.remove(at: index) collectionView.reloadData() }
```